# No error on ts-node-dev script, but errors occurred on SERVERLESS offline(and deploy) script

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless, typeorm

I have a serverless http API-server project.

```
{
  "name": "ants-test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Serverless webpack example using Typescript",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "offline": "set NODE_ENV=development&& sls offline --port 5003",
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/server.ts",
    "deploy_p": "set NODE_ENV=production&& sls deploy --verbose"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@paypal/checkout-server-sdk": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/ejs": "^2.6.3",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.3",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.2",
    "@types/koa": "^2.0.48",
    "@types/koa-router": "^7.0.41",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.478.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.2",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "koa": "^2.7.0",
    "koa-body": "^4.1.0",
    "koa-ejs": "^4.2.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "serverless-http": "^2.0.2",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.10.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.10",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.40",
    "tslint": "^5.17.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.17",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0"
  },
  "author": "The serverless webpack authors (https://github.com/elastic-coders/serverless-webpack)",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I'm making serverless project with using node, koa, typescript, typeorm to upload on AWS. I'm developing this project with `ts-node-dev` library(`yarn dev` script). *No error with ts-node-dev*.

But when I tried to deploy to AWS by `serverless deploy` script, deployment has been succeeded. But if I entered in the endpoint, It shows up `Internal Server Error` **error**.

This is error logs

```
TypeError: require is not a function
    at Object../node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:3:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object../node_modules/formidable/lib/index.js (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\formidable\lib\index.js:1:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object../node_modules/koa-body/index.js (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-body\index.js:18:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../src/app.ts (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\src\app.ts:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module../src/serverless.ts (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\src\serverless.ts:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:83:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\serverless.js:87:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.createHandler (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\node_modules\serverless-offline\src\functionHelper.js:215:15)
    at handler (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\node_modules\serverless-offline\src\ApiGateway.js:485:40)
    at module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:41:33)
    at Object.internals.handler (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:48)
    at exports.execute (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:36)
    at Request._lifecycle (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:312:68)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

So I tried to remove koa-body library in app.ts. Then, I deployed the codes. New error messages has been printed. like

```
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Address" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
      at new RepositoryNotFoundError (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\typeorm\error\RepositoryNotFoundError.js:11:1)
      at EntityManager../node_modules/typeorm/entity-manager/EntityManager.js.EntityManager.getRepository (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\EntityManager.js:555:1)
      at Connection../node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js.Connection.getRepository (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:347:1)
      at getRepository (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\typeorm\index.js:272:1)
      at ./src/api/index.ts.routes.get (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\src\api\index.ts:10:38)
      at dispatch (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:44:1)
      at next (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:45:1)
      at C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-router\lib\router.js:346:1
      at dispatch (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:44:1)
      at C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:36:1
      at dispatch (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa-router\lib\router.js:351:1)
      at dispatch (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:42:1)
      at C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:34:1
      at Application.handleRequest (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:162:1)
      at handleRequest (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:144:1)
      at request (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\serverless-http\lib\framework\get-framework.js:9:1)
      at provider (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\serverless-http\serverless-http.js:19:1)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

app.initialize Error { Error: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Packet.asError (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:708:1)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:1)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:408:1)
    at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:70:1)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:1)
    at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (C:\Work Place\sample\ants-test1\.webpack\service\src\webpack:\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:77:1)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlState: '08004',
  sqlMessage:
   'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client' }
```

It has not occurred on ts-node-dev either. But occurred on serverless script.

below is my codes.

↓ serverless.yml

```
service:
  name: ants-test1

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x

functions:
  app:
    handler: src/serverless.handler

    events:
      - http:
         path: /
         method: ANY
      - http:
         path: /{any+}
         method: ANY
```

↓ serverless.ts

```
import serverless from 'serverless-http';
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda';
import app from './app';

const serverlessApp = serverless(app);

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, context) => {
  return await serverlessApp(event, context)
}
```

↓ app.ts

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import routes from './api/index';
// import koaBody from 'koa-body';
import {db} from './db';

const app = new Koa();
// app.use(koaBody({multipart: true}));
app.use(routes.routes()).use(routes.allowedMethods());
app.use(ctx => {
    ctx.body = "Hello server."
});

const initialize = async () => {
    try {
        await db();
        console.log('REMOTE database is successfully connected!');
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("app.initialize Error", e);
    }
}

initialize();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
      await next();
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.status = err.status || 500;
      ctx.body = err.message;
      ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);
    }
  });

export default app;
```

↓ webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ],
  },
};
```

↓ db.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

export const db = async () => {
    return await createConnection({
        type: "mysql",
        host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
        username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
        timezone: 'Z',
        entities: [
            __dirname + "/entity/*.ts"
        ],
        synchronize: true,
    })
}
```

above code work with `ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/server.ts` script successfully, but the code shows the error on `serverless offline`script and `serverless deploy` script.

I don't understand Why two things make different results..

Please let me know how to fix this problem. And if it's not enough to solve, I will add.(and vice versa)

Thank you for reading a long question.

Comment: I think the error with repository configuration. When you try to deploy, the deployment script can't be able to find repository.

Comment: @KiranManiya Thank you for your answer. Could I know the `repository configuration` you said exactly? Is it for serverless?

Comment: Was this item ever resolved? I have the same issue

Comment: @Stuart
So sorry. Unfortunately not. I just decided to use the ec2 of AWS.